# SQL Server 2019 :: does features apply to previous compatibility level?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2019, compatibility-level

I have a SQL Server 2019 instance on my hands but all database in it are set to Compatibility Level 110 (SQL Server 2012).

I would like to rebuild a few indexes with the options:

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON [MyIndexName] 
REBUILD WITH(FILLFACTOR = 80, 
                ONLINE = ON, 
                SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON
                RESUMABLE = ON,
                OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = ON);
```

My question is, as `RESUMABLE = ON` and `OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = ON` are features introduced from SQL Server 2019 will they apply to my databases as well even if they are still on Compatibility Level 110?

Comment: Some features do, some do not (the majority not). The simplest way for you to find out would be to run the statement, but I'm pretty sure it won't work. (Side note `RESUMABLE` was added in 2017, not 2019).

Comment: The features typically do (it's the same engine and the same DB file format) but whether or not the *syntax* is accepted is a crapshoot. Sometimes you can work around this by running the statement from an `sp_` prefixed procedure in `master` (that's an unsupported hack, though).

Comment: Thank you guys, I cannot believe Microsoft isn't clear about this :¦

Comment: It's because the feature is primarily intended for databases in which ongoing development isn't happening. [Microsoft recommend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver15): "For new development work, or when an existing application requires use of new features such as ... plan to upgrade the database compatibility level to the latest available."

Comment: I suppose the *real* question then, @FrancescoMantovani, is why are you *not* updating the compatibility level of your database(s)?

Comment: Because before jumping from 110 to 150 I have to check if all the applications that are written in VB and Access will survive.

Comment: Then you should be completing those tests first, in your Development and/or other test environements, and then worrying about implementation of new features *afterwards* @FrancescoMantovani . When updating to a new version, you need to ensure that **existing** functionality is maintained first before considering new functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reply is: we cannot tell.

- “[…] New features may work under older compatibility levels but beware of SET options.” (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverstorageengine/whats-the-difference-between-database-version-and-database-compatibility-level )
- “[…]For pre-existing databases running at lower compatibility levels, as long as the application does not need to leverage enhancements that are only available in a higher database compatibility level, it is a valid approach to maintain the previous database compatibility level. For new development work, or when an existing application requires use of new features such as Intelligent Query Processing, as well as some new Transact-SQL, plan to upgrade the database compatibility level to the latest available. For more information, see Compatibility levels and Database Engine upgrades.” (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver15 )

I also asked to [Randolph West](https://bornsql.ca/blog/deprecated-and-discontinued-features-in-sql-server/#comments) on a post and the reply is: "*Some features apply to the instance level, while some apply only to databases in the correct compatibility level. Optimize for sequential key is a 150-level feature.*"

So we just need to try out on a test environment as suggested in the comments above.